# how to real time display input value to display to input name same with div id? or any other way?

Tags: javascript, input, real-time

i need to real-time display input value with jquery.
how to change div text as same with input name or or other way?

```
$('.inputs').keyup(function(){
  var namer = $('.inputs').attr('name');
  $('#' + namer).text($(this).val());
});
```

I expect XX named input value to display in XX id with div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to update the div text from the input (single way), do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText">
<div id="dynamicText">Original Text</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#inputText').keyup(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('#dynamicText').text(text);
    });
</script>
```

And if you want to show the div text as input's original value:

```
<input type="text" id="inputText">
<div id="dynamicText">Original Text</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var OriginalText = $('#dynamicText').text();
    $('#inputText').val(OriginalText);
    $('#inputText').keyup(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('#dynamicText').text(text);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks to anwser it helped a lot. my final result is https://jsfiddle.net/rhgns35u/

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure you run your code within a `document.ready()` callback it seems to be working ok:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputs').keyup(function(){
    var namer = $('.inputs').attr('name');
    $('#' + namer).text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="someInputName" class="inputs"/>
<div id="someInputName"></div>
```

Comment: problem was my input name had "[]" . i removed it then solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by writing obtained text in target element withing the keyup function

```
$('.inputs').keyup(function(){
  var namer = $('.inputs').attr('name');
  $('target element').text(namer);
});
```